# Remove unwanted th, td and tr tags from Django generated form

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, w3c

I finished an auction app with a search form in the navbar.

The search form model is in my **forms.py** file (it isn't a ModelForm because I don't need to save the search form data in any database model) :

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(label="",
                            min_length=1,
                            max_length=50,
                            widget=forms.TextInput
                            (attrs={'class':'form-control mr-sm-2',
                            'placeholder':'Name or category',
                            'type':'search',
                            'aria-label':'Search'
                            }))
```

And the form is rendered in my **layout.html** like this :

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'auctions:search' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ searchform }}
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Search Form:

[image: 1]

There is no issue with the rendered form (the style is like I wanted it to be), but when I look at the source code of the rendered page, there is some unwated tr, td and th tags :

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="glVkeNbCkWjiInGZ2cwORkXSu48otl5TPnJAAGxzdhzzdKFSSMxJVyRk9oK0HNmk">
                    <tr><th><label for="id_search">Search:</label></th><td><input type="search" name="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Name or category" aria-label="Search" maxlength="50" minlength="1" required id="id_search"></td></tr>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

I tried to set `label_suffix=""` in my **views.py** like this, it deletes the label tag but not the tr, td and th tags :

```
return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
    "auctions": auctions,
    "searchform": SearchForm(label_suffix="")
})
```

Those tags are causing errors in the W3C validator, so I had a few questions about this issue :

1 . Is it important ? I am new to programming and i don't know if this will cause serious issues for my app.

2 . Is it caused by the Django form or the Bootstrap style ?

3 . Is there a way to remove these tags ?

Thank you for your help,

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The question of the importance of adherence to standards is really up to you. Most browsers will process the result even if there's no parent `<table>` tag (which is what I assume W3C validation is pointing to?).
2. It's not bootstrap. There are `<tr>` and `<th>` tags being added to your HTML which means this is the output from django (think of bootstrap as mostly CSS). In this case it looks to me like these tags are being added by the forms.Form class (or related templates)
3. You can remove the tags by using [django's built-in form rendering options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options). For example, you could change `{{ searchform }}` to `{{ searchform.as_p }}` for a form that's using

   instead of  and similar.

The gist is that you'll want to read the form rending documentation linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @kerasbaz, at first I tried with form.as_p and I was having some style issues, and then I found this in the doc :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

So I changed `{{ searchform }}` to `{{ searchform.search }}` in my **layout.html** and the issue was resolved.

Thank you for your help,